# POSTMAN equivalent of --upload-file option in curl

Tags: google-cloud-platform, curl, postman, google-cloud-storage

I am using signed url to upload files to GCP Cloud Storage. With curl, the upload is working fine:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' --upload-file audience.csv <signed-url>
```

However, if I try to upload a file in POSTMAN, it does not work.

In postman, I selected PUT method and pasted the URL. I tried to upload the file as binary data. That did not work.

[image]

I also tried to upload the file as Form data. That did not work as well.
[image]

What is the right way to call a GCP signed url in POSTMAN and upload a file?

Answer (score 0):

curl sends the file raw in the request body, so `binary` is the correct mode. you probably just forgot to add the `Content-Type: text/csv` header in Postman.
[image]